# Problem with images URL after filter applying

Tags: functions, filters, urls, customization

I have this code in my functions.php file:

```
function user_content_replace($content) {

    // it's not a URL, let's apply the replacement
    if (!filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        $replacement = '$1.</p><p>$2';
        return preg_replace("/([^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*){1}\\.([^\\.]*)/s", $replacement, $content);
    } else { // it's a URL, just return the string
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content','user_content_replace', 99);
```

This code replaces every third dot in content with dot+closed+open paragraph. This because it is the best way in this moment to format non-formatted great amount of texts and posts.

But: this code also changes **Images URLs** so all my images does not contain dot before extension but `**imagename.</p><p>jpg**`instead of **imagename.jpg**

Even if I put URL validation - same problem. Any advice please?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Why include a paragraph every third dot? Also, WordPress already applies [`wpautop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) to content, why it doesn't work for you?. By the way, you have a typo: `filter_var($string` should be `filter_var($content`.

Comment: OK, it is not typo (works same with string or content variable) and reason for this is a lot of non.formatted imported posts, so this is one way to create line breaks after every three sentences.
But I dont know why this code changes images URLs?

the_content does not includes image paths...so I dont get it

Comment: As it sounded before, you do filter nothing with `filter_var()` function. Secondly, it's most likely a problem with your `preg_replace()` `pattern`. I don't understand the double escapes `\\\` there.

Comment: @Eager2Learn, note that `$string` is an undefined variable in your code. If it is not a typo it is bug. Note also that I'm not saying that it is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = 'Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3! Sentence 4... Sentence 5… Sentence 6! Sentence 7. Sentence 8. Sentence 9… Sentence 10... Sentence 11. ';

$sentences_per_paragraph = 3; // settings

$pattern = '~(?<=[.?!…])\s+~'; // some punctuation and trailing space(s)

$sentences_array = preg_split($pattern, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // get sentences into array

$sentences_count = count($sentences_array); // count sentences

$output = ''; // new content init

// see PHP modulus
for($i = 0; $i < $sentences_count; $i++) {
    if($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i == 0) { //divisible by settings and is first
        $output .= "<p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // add paragraph and the first sentence
    } elseif($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i > 0) { //divisible by settings and not first
        $output .= "</p><p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // close and open paragraph, add the first sentence
    } else {
        $output .= $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // concatenate other sentences
    }
}

$output .= "</p>"; // close the last paragraph

echo $output;
```

**Note**: It's a very rough code that does not check the deeper problems.

For more info:

- [PHP modulus](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)
- [preg_split()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: Beautiful, thank you mate! I did not work with this function before!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Max Yudin this is an answer to my problem:

```
function user_content_replace($content) {

$sentences_per_paragraph = 3; // settings

$pattern = '~(?<=[.?!…])\s+~'; // some punctuation and trailing space(s)

$sentences_array = preg_split($pattern, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // get sentences into array

$sentences_count = count($sentences_array); // count sentences

$output = ''; // new content init

// see PHP modulus
for($i = 0; $i < $sentences_count; $i++) {
    if($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i == 0) { //divisible by settings and is first
        $output .= "<p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // add paragraph and the first sentence
    } elseif($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i > 0) { //divisible by settings and not first
        $output .= "</p><p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // close and open paragraph, add the first sentence
    } else {
        $output .= $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // concatenate other sentences
    }
}

$output .= "</p>"; // close the last paragraph

echo $output;
}
add_filter('the_content','user_content_replace', 99);
```